# Getting the error 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed.'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

While trying to call a stored procedure which is on a linked server, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed.

I tried using the `openquery`, but it is not sufficing my situation as I need to run test case automation scripts which contains many lines of code. When I am trying to use

```
EXEC LinkedServer.Database.dbo.sp_executesql
```

I am getting another error saying

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Database'

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag, since this is clearly SQL Server.

Comment: If you really called your database `Database`, you'll need to escape it as `[Database]` before that's a legal four-part identifier. But don't call your database `Database`, seriously. Also, consider `EXEC ... AT [LinkedServer]` rather than invoking `sp_executesql` remotely (I'm skeptical that will even work).